# How to export a webservice as WAR

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, war

I have generated a web-service off of a wsdl. I am now at the point of wanting to export a war file to web-sphere or Tomcat. When it comes to making a WAR file I am having difficulties. Do I need to use the WSIMPORT tool to generate classes? if so I read it should be the interface/impl but the service generated 2 of each (different). Will I need to create a web.xml file? and a xml file regarding the framework? Overall I'm asking what steps need to be taken to take a generated web-service from a WSDL create a WAR file from it? Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you following tutorial on deploying a web-service using JAX-WS on Tomcat.

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_glassfish5.html#wp106350

Comment: Will every generated web service be considered a jaw-ws?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: you said to look at a tutorial regarding jax-ws. Are you saying that every wsdl you generate a webservice in eclipse will be considered a jax-ws server?

Comment: No. You can deploy many applications containing a WSDL as a web service project. Typically each application contains a WSDL file describing services to its clients.